# difference between pci_alloc_consistent and dma_alloc_coherent

Tags: network-programming, driver, linux-device-driver, dma, pci-e

I am working on pcie based network driver. Different examples use one of **pci_alloc_consistent** or **dma_alloc_coherent** to get memory for transmission and reception descriptors. Which one is better if any and what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The difference is subtle but quite important.
`pci_alloc_consistent()` is the older function of the two and legacy drivers still use it.
Nowadays, `pci_alloc_consistent()` just calls `dma_alloc_coherent()`.

The difference? The type of the allocated memory.

- `pci_alloc_consistent()` - Allocates memory of type `GFP_ATOMIC`.
  Allocation does not sleep, for use in e.g. interrupt handlers, bottom
  halves.
- `dma_alloc_coherent()`- You specify yourself what type of memory to
  allocate. You should not use the high priority `GFP_ATOMIC` memory
  unless you need it and in most cases, you will be fine with
  `GFP_KERNEL` allocations.

Kernel 3.18 definition of `pci_alloc_consistent()` is very simple, namely:

```
 static inline void *
 pci_alloc_consistent(struct pci_dev *hwdev, size_t size,
                      dma_addr_t *dma_handle)
 {
         return dma_alloc_coherent(hwdev == NULL ? NULL : &hwdev->dev, size, dma_handle, GFP_ATOMIC);
 }
```

In short, use `dma_alloc_coherent()`.